# Count distinct id with case

Tags: t-sql

So say I have a list IDs with values, like so:

```
ID  VALUE
1   A
1   NULL
1   B
2   NULL
3   A
```

And I want to count distinct ID for values that equal A OR B (at least one)

The answer should be 2, since there are 2 IDs that have either A or B value.

If I do a `COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN ...` I'm unable to get the unique IDs.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct Id)
from tbl
where value in ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to filter for values A or B, and then count the distinct Ids listed, as below:

```
declare @t table (id int not null, 
                  value char(1) null);

insert into @t 
values 
(1,'A'),
(1,NULL),
(1,'B'),
(2,NULL),
(3,'A');

select 
   count(distinct id) 
from @t 
where value in ('A','B');
```